# How to create an associative array out of list generated by a variable in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, variables

I am connecting to an API and pulling down a list of managers and the markets they have access to with PowerShell. I am then using replace commands to change those markets into corresponding mailboxes for said markets that will be shared with the managers based on market.

```
#Pull WITH jobprofileid
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetARDIR -Method GET -ContentType $content  -Headers $headers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

#Gather Response 
$response | Out-File $Outfile

#Get Email and Managed Org
$alignment = Get-Content $Outfile | Select-String -Pattern workemail,supervisoryorgmanaged

$cleanalignment = $alignment -replace "blah"

$fullalignment = $cleanalignment.trim()

$fullalignment
```

Then $fullalignment returns a list like

```
manager1@company.com
market1@company.com  market2@company.com
manager2@comapny.com
market3@company.com  market4@company.com
manager3@company.com 
market5@company.com
manager4@company.com
market6@manager.com
```

Some managers will have multiple markets applied while others will only have one. The managers markets are the ones directly under their name in the list. My next step will be auto assigning these mailboxes but I am unsure how to be go about that with the list I have. I believe I will need to create an associative array to be able to grab each manager and their market to assign them. How would I go about that or is that not even the path I should be pursuing?

Sample of API data

```
{
    "data":  {
                 "0":  {
                           "index":  11,
                           "firstname":  "null",
                           "lastname":  "null",
                           "fullname":  "null",
                           "jobprofilename":  "null",
                           "jobprofileid":  "null",
                           "workphonenumber":  "[\"null\"]",
                           "worklocationname":  "null",
                           "worklocationsuporg":  "null",
                           "worklocationid":  "null",
                           "worklocationid4":  "null",
                           "altworklocationid":  null,
                           "altworklocationid4":  null,
                           "homeemail":  "null",
                           "workemail":  "[\"employee@company.com\"]",
                           "workstreetaddress":  "null",
                           "workcity":  "null",
                           "workstate":  "null",
                           "workpostalcode":  null,
                           "workcountry":  "null",
                           "homestreetaddress":  "null",
                           "homecity":  "null",
                           "homestate":  "null",
                           "homecountry":  "null",
                           "homepostalcode":  null,
                           "employeeid":  null,
                           "homephone":  "null",
                           "title":  "null",
                           "department":  "null",
                           "departmentid":  null,
                           "company":  "null",
                           "organizationid":  "null",
                           "companyid":  "null",
                           "managername":  "null",
                           "managerid":  null,
                           "fzsitenumber":  null,
                           "hiredate":  "null",
                           "dob":  null,
                           "supervisoryorg":  "[\"null\"]",
                           "supervisoryorgmanaged": "[\"Stores of Carolinas\",\"Stores of Georgia East\"]",
                           "toolsroles":  "[\"null"]",
                           "termdatetime":  null,
                           "contingentworker":  null,
                           "remoteworker":  null,
                           "lastaction":  "null",
                           "lastdatetime":  "null",
                           "ldapsync":  null,
                           "tangosync":  null,
                           "corrigosync":  null,
                           "prophixsync":  null,
                           "procurosync":  null
                       },
                "1":   {
                           "index":  1207,
                           "firstname":  "null",
                           "lastname":  "null",
                           "fullname":  "null",
                           "jobprofilename":  "nulls",
                           "jobprofileid":  "null",
                           "workphonenumber":  "[\"null\"]",
                           "worklocationname":  "null",
                           "worklocationsuporg":  "null",
                           "worklocationid":  "null",
                           "worklocationid4":  "null",
                           "altworklocationid":  null,
                           "altworklocationid4":  null,
```

Comment: It kind of feels like your entire code sample is a home-brewed attempt at parsing a file format that could probably be done with a single call to```ConvertFrom -Csv``` or ```ConvertFrom-Json``` or something - can you post an example of the raw response from the api so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: @mclayton I added a snippit of the API return. I also added a part to the original code where I Convert the API response to Json.

Comment: Your updated sample doesn’t seem to contain ```workemail``` or ```supervisoryorgmanaged``` - can you add a sample that includes those fields?

Comment: @mclayton My apologies, I have updated the sample to the entire pull of one employee from the response returned from the API. The fields are included now.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit of a strange structure, tbh - you'd normally expect "employees" to be a json array, but it looks like they're represented as numbered properties on the "data" object. I'm presuming the second employee is numbered "1" or something? Could you add a second record just to show how it represents multiple employees?

Comment: @mclayton I added a small snippet of what the next employee info return would be. The employee is numbered 1. The rest of the return follows the same format as the 0 employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Intro

Your json format is a bit unusual because of a couple of quirks:

- **Quirk 1** - the list of employees is represented as a set of numeric *properties* on the `data` object like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "0": { ... employee ... },
    "1": { ... employee ... },
    ...
    "N": { ... employee ... }
  }
}
```

instead of as a json array like this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    { ... employee ... },
    { ... employee ... },
    ...
    { ... employee ... }
  ]
}
```

- **Quirk 2** - the `workemail` and `supervisoryorgmanaged` properties are strings that contain embedded json - that is:

```json
    "0": {
      "workemail": "[\"employee@company.com\"]",
      "supervisoryorgmanaged": "[\"Stores of Carolinas\",\"Stores of Georgia East\"]",
    },
```

rather than

```json
    "0": {
      "workemail": [
        "employee@company.com"
      ],
      "supervisoryorgmanaged": [
        "Stores of Carolinas",
        "Stores of Georgia East"
      ]
    },
```

But that's ok - now that we can see it, we can work around it...

### Answer

So first of all, you can ditch most of your sample code and just use

```
# note - no trailing ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri         $GetARDIR `
    -Method      "GET" `
    -ContentType $content `
    -Headers     $headers;
```

That gives you a structured object that you can process without doing lots of string manipulation.

I'll use this sample data so you can cut&paste it to try out rather than have to query the api, but the return value from `Invoke-RestMethod` with be the same shape:

```
$response = @"
{
  "data": {
    "0": {
      "workemail": "[\"jim@company.com\"]",
      "supervisoryorgmanaged": "[\"Stores of North\",\"Stores of South\"]"
    },
    "1": {
      "workemail": "[\"bob@company.com\"]",
      "supervisoryorgmanaged": "[\"Stores of East\",\"Stores of West\"]"
    }
  }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

To massage the employees into an array we can do this:

```
# get an array of all the employee objects
$employees = $response.data.psobject.properties.value;

# show the results
$employees
# workemail           supervisoryorgmanaged
# ---------           ---------------------
# ["jim@company.com"] ["Stores of North","Stores of South"]
# ["bob@company.com"] ["Stores of East","Stores of West"]
```

This basically queries the `data` object's metadata to get its property *definitions* ("0", "1", etc) as an array and then uses [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3) to read the value of each property.

Then we need to parse the embedded json to turn *that* into structured objects which we can extract the values from:

```
$employees = $employees | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        # assume there's only one workemail address
        "workemail"             = @($_.workemail | ConvertFrom-Json)[0]
        "supervisoryorgmanaged" = @($_.supervisoryorgmanaged | ConvertFrom-Json)
        # add a new property to hold the email addresses
        "orgaddresses"          = $null
    }
}

$employees
# workemail       supervisoryorgmanaged              orgaddresses
# ---------       ---------------------              ------------
# jim@company.com {Stores of North, Stores of South}
# bob@company.com {Stores of East, Stores of West}
```

Next, we need a lookup hashtable (your associative array) to map organisation names to email addresses:

```
$lookups = @{
    "Stores of North" = "north@company.com"
    "Stores of South" = "south@company.com"
    "Stores of East"  = "east@company.com"
    "Stores of West"  = "west@company.com"
}
```

and then we can apply the lookups to the organisations for each employee:

```
foreach( $employee in $employees )
{
    $employee.orgaddresses = @(
        $employee.supervisoryorgmanaged `
            | foreach-object {
                $lookups[$_]
           }
    );
}

$employees
# workemail       supervisoryorgmanaged              orgaddresses
# ---------       ---------------------              ------------
# jim@company.com {Stores of North, Stores of South} {north@company.com, south@company.com}
# bob@company.com {Stores of East, Stores of West}   {east@company.com, west@company.com}
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
# get the raw employee data out of the response
$employees = $response.data.psobject.properties.value;

# parse the workemail and supervisoryorgmanaged properties
$employees = $employees | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        # assume there's only one workemail address
        "workemail"             = @($_.workemail | ConvertFrom-Json)[0]
        "supervisoryorgmanaged" = @($_.supervisoryorgmanaged | ConvertFrom-Json)
        # add a new property to hold the email addresses
        "orgaddresses"          = $null
    }
}

# map the organisations to eamil addresses
foreach( $employee in $employees )
{
    $employee.orgaddresses = @(
        $employee.supervisoryorgmanaged `
            | foreach-object {
                $lookups[$_]
           }
    );
}

$employees
# workemail       supervisoryorgmanaged              orgaddresses
# ---------       ---------------------              ------------
# jim@company.com {Stores of North, Stores of South} {north@company.com, south@company.com}
# bob@company.com {Stores of East, Stores of West}   {east@company.com, west@company.com}
```

Your question isn't clear what you wan to do with the data afterwards, but hopefully this is enough to unblock your current issue, and you can adapt it to whatever you need to do from there...

Comment: Thank you so much for the thoughtful and well written out response, I really do appreciate the effort! I will have time to review all of this tomorrow but thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I have worked through this and everything is working as expected until the last foreach. I get an error saying an empty pipe element is not allow before the foreach-object { $lookups. I have messed around with removing the pipe and adding variables before the pipe but I still cant get it to work. I get an "Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null" error then it prints the response with the supervisororgmanaged in the orgaddress field. Am I overlooking something from your post?

Comment: @TaylorStevens - there were a couple of syntax glitches that worked fine in PowerShell Core but *not* Windows PowerShell - I've fixed those if you want to try again...